# Images not working using Featured post

Tags: images, post-thumbnails, site-url

I have recently moved a wordpress website `abc.com` to `xyz.com`, And `xyz.com` functionality is good and working well.

And i have created a `post` with a image in it using `Featured Image`, and when i `publish` this post, its not displaying images in it.
And when i check the `URL` of image using `Inspect Element`, i see the location as

`http://www.abc.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/11/ACFA7.jpg` instead of
`http://www.xyz.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/11/ACFA7.jpg` .

And when i changed this to correct url.. then images are working good using inspect element.

And i have changed the `permalinks` and `wp-options` in database for `siteurl` to `xyz.com` , is there any thing more i need to configure or update into site or database anywhere.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe there are some root-links that you haven't changed.

Please follow these steps

1. Login to admin section www.xyz.com/wp-admin
2. Navigate to **settings->general->** and change the **'Site Address (URL)'** and  **'WordPress Address (URL)'**.

Also please check the permalinks and settings->media there is an upload directory and the default wordpress location is **wp-content/uploads**, check if it is different for you.

Comment: Now!, its working i forgot to update `Setting->media` and **wp-content/uploads**